# Removing redundant points contained in pixel using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

When rendering a tile, many points in a **csv** file are located in the same pixel, which are not necessary since they all overlap each other in this pixel.

Can I remove these redundant points only rendering a point in this pixel?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: How do you define "pixel"? Do you have a raster that defines it? Or do you mean a pixel at screen resolution for the current map scale?

Comment: @underdark sir, here, *pixel* is the pixel on the 256x256 raster image(a tile under some zoom level), which has its own geographical resolution. I am a gis newbie, imo, when we draw this image one the screen, it becomes the pixel on the screen.